# functions vs repeated code

Tags: php, function, code-generation

I am writing some PHP code to create PDFs using the FPDF library. And I basically use the same 4 lines of code to print every line of the document. I was wondering which is more efficient, repeating these 4 lines over and over, or would making it into a function be better?  I'm curious because it feels like a function would have a larger overhead becuse the function would only be 4 lines long.


The code I am questioning looks like this:

```
$pdf->checkIfPageBreakNeeded($lineheight * 2, true);
$text = ' label';
$pdf->MultiCell(0, $lineheight, $text, 1, 'L', 1);
$text = $valueFromForm;
$pdf->MultiCell(0, $lineheight, $text, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Ln();
```

Comment: Don't you have a MACRO option as well in PHP?

Comment: How many times are you repeating these 4 lines.

Comment: @Shaihi: No. PHP is interpreted, not compiled. (HiPHoP notwithstanding)

Comment: If you need to add or remove lines from your pdf, do you then have to delete or paste these lines?  Couldn't you use a loop?

Comment: Let's say you have 165 copies of those 6 lines. Then you rename `checkIfPageBreakNeeded()`. Then you do a `sed` to update those 165 copies. Then you come to Stackoverflow for help, since that super simple self evident `sed` somehow broke your entire program.

Comment: You've already repeated these lines "roughly 165 times"!?  The alarms that tell you it should be a function should have been ringing roughly 164 times ago.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should answer it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself
and
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html

> Curly's Law, Do One Thing, is
>   reflected in several core principles
>   of modern software development:
>
> - **Don't Repeat Yourself**
>
>   If you have more than one way to express the same thing, at some point
>     the two or three different
>     representations will most likely fall
>     out of step with each other. Even if
>     they don't, you're guaranteeing
>     yourself the headache of maintaining
>     them in parallel whenever a change
>     occurs. And change will occur. Don't
>     repeat yourself is important if you
>     want flexible and maintainable
>     software.
> - **Once and Only Once**
>
>   Each and every declaration of behavior should occur once, and only
>     once. This is one of the main goals,
>     if not the main goal, when refactoring
>     code. The design goal is to eliminate
>     duplicated declarations of behavior,
>     typically by merging them or replacing
>     multiple similar implementations with
>     a unifying abstraction.
> - **Single Point of Truth**
>
>   Repetition leads to inconsistency and code that is subtly
>     broken, because you changed only some
>     repetitions when you needed to change
>     all of them. Often, it also means that
>     you haven't properly thought through
>     the organization of your code. Any
>     time you see duplicate code, that's a
>     danger sign. Complexity is a cost;
>     don't pay it twice.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than asking yourself which is more efficient you should instead ask yourself which is more maintainable.

Writing a function is far more maintainable.

Answer (score 11):

> I'm curious because it feels like a
>   function would have a larger overhead
>   becuse the function would only be 4
>   lines long.

This is where spaghetti comes from.

Defininely encapsulate it into a function and call it.  The overhead that you fear is the worst kind of premature optimization.

DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Make it a function.  Function call overhead is pretty small these days.  In general you'll be able to save far more time by finding better high-level algorithms than fiddling with such low-level details.  And making and keeping it correct is *far* easier with such a function.  For what shall it profit a man, if he shall gain a little speed, and lose his program's correctness?

Answer (score 2):

A function is certainly preferable, especially if you have to go back later to make a change.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about overhead; worry about yourself, a year in the future, trying to debug this.

In the light of the above, Don't Repeat Yourself and make a tiny function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the valuable answers about the far more important topic of maintainability;  I'd like to add a little something on the question of overhead.

I don't understand why you fear that a four line function would have a greater overhead.

1. In a compiled language, a good compiler would probably be able to inline it anyway, if appropriate.
2. In an interpreted language (such as PHP) the interpreter has to parse all of this repeated code each time it is encountered, *at runtime*.  To me, that suggests that repetition might carry an even greater overhead than  a function call.
3. Worrying about function call overhead here is ghastly premature optimisation.  In matters like this, the only way to really know which is faster, is to profile it.

Make it work, make it right, make it fast.  In that order.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead is actually very small and wont be causing a big difference in your application.
Would u rather these small overhead, but have a easier program to maintain, or u want to save the mere millisecond but take hours to correct small changes which are repeated.

If you ask me or other developer out there, we definitely want the 1st option.
So go on with the function. U may not be maintaining the code today, but when u do, u will hate yourself for trying to save that mere milliseconds